# Why is my mobile responsive css not working?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, styles, responsive

for a particular div, I'm trying to have padding-left:10%; for desktops and padding-left:0; for mobiles. However, the code below doesn't seem to work. Hope you can help. Thank you.

CSS Code:

```
    @media (max-width:960px) {
        #tdpadding { padding-left:0%; }
    }
    
    @media (min-width:961px) {
    #tdpadding { padding-left:10%; }
    }
```

Inline Code:

```
    <div class="tdpadding">
    some text here
    </div>
```

Comment: Typo: You confused your ID and Class selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it into .tdpadding { padding-left:0%; }

Answer (score 1):

your using css id selector  prefix '#tdpadding'  so you should use a class selector prefix '.tdpadding'

```
.tdpadding { padding-left:0%; }
```

this code should work